# How to return a view in asp.net mvc3 application without ending the current request, If possible

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to generate a pdf on a fly at runtime from a database, The application is working fine, but I am wondering if I can show a progress bar until the pdf is generated `with out using ajax.`

Here is my Action to generate PDF

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF(){
    //This Generates PDF
    return ...
}
```

Now I want to show a progress bar info until the PDF is generated, some thing like this

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF(){
        //show progress
        ...............
        //This Generates PDF
        return View();
    }

public ActionResult ShowProgress(){
   //Show progress

    ......
    //return to GeneratePDF to show pdf when it is ready
    return RedirectToAction("GeneratePDF");
}
```

I appreciate for any suggestions on how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this.  Even if you could continue like this on the server side, once the browser gets a response from its initial request it won't know what to do with anything else that comes in later.

The HTTP protocol in fundamentally built on a concept of request-response, request-response - and it's the browser that's in the driver's seat, not the server.  AJAX is the way to go for this kind of client-side UI richness.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. That is what i have in mind, I was just wondering if there is a way and you are right the last option will be to use Ajax.

Comment: Like I said, the nature of the HTTP protocol itself would prevent this from working.  The only other porssibility would be to use a client-side framework that hides the AJAX stuff from you.  I don't if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript or jQuery to show an animated loading gif.

Ie:

$('.loading').show();